# What comes in between predecessor and successor?

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes, morphology

I'd like a good word for "current item in a succession of items".

Let's say I am looking ahead, towards my successor.
Back behind me, I can also see my predecessor.
What am I?

I'd hate to use the overly-verbose "current object of focus among a succession of such objects", and yet "current" doesn't quite cut it either. "Currentssor"?

The context is programming (coming up with descriptive variable names) but I'm really interested in what's true in general.

Comment: Are you thinking in terms of accessing records in a database table or file? If you are the most usual term _is_ 'current row' (or line or record)

Answer (score 11):

I think *incumbent* is what you're looking for.

> holding an indicated position, role, office, etc., currently: the incumbent officers of the club.
>
> (dictionary.com)

Comment: I like this answer, and I've up-voted it, but perhaps "one sitting" (or, "sitting item") should also be considered (as in "a sitting president").

Answer (score 4):

A *[locus](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Genetic_locus)* is the position of a gene on a chromosome.

As part of a sequence, a locus has both predecessor and successor (either of which, as in any sequence, can be null).

When talking about, say, a linked list, I find it more elegant and concise to say *the locus of the list iterator* rather than *the node to which list iterator is currently pointing*.

---

Commenters have pointed out the hazards of borrowing an overloaded term like *locus*; if you want to use a more standard term, *current element* is well-understood.

Comment: I agree with *locus*, though just *current* is fine. In the context of iterators, *referent* is perhaps more appropriate, as an iterator is a generalised pointer.

Comment: I would caution against the use of *locus*, which has a different meaning in mathematics (related in that both refer to position, but in mathematics a locus is a *set* of points which have some particular property, not a single point in a sequence)

Comment: Jon, referent seems to be what I was looking for. Care to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are a referrer referencing your predecessor and successor http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referrer

Comment: That's a bit of an "out of the box" thinking.

Answer (score -1):

'contemporary' is the word  !!

Comment: Please see how the other answers have answered the question and explain *why* this is the word.