# A word for a successor without an incumbent

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an individual who in the future will take on a role but there isn't anyone currently in that role (that is, no incumbent)? So for instance, a new job is created and I want to describe what the person will do in that role. I could say "The successful candidate will do this" but I would like to use a single term like successor.

Related to: [What comes in between predecessor and successor?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60562/what-comes-in-between-predecessor-and-successor)

Comment: Since there is none to follow, nobody can succeed (in the sense of follow). But one could say 'the job-holder will do such and such'.

Comment: Is “in the future” an important consideration? Or is “first” enough? Or are you simply focusing on “no incumbent”?

Comment: X will be Y in the newly created position. There is no word for the person if the position, job or post is new.

Comment: The person is the "XXX-designate":  Governor-designate, mayor-designate, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't speak about the [future incumbent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incumbent_(ecclesiastical)#Nomination_and_admission_into_office)?

Comment: You could sidestep the issue by saying "this role will involve X, Y, and Z". If you must have a word for the actual person, I would say "the appointee will do X, Y, and Z".

Answer (score 1):

`title`-elect or `title`-in-waiting are commonly used for positions in the monarchy, political office or industry. Perhaps that could suit your use-case.

Comment: Hi, GlitchC. The downvoter didn't leave a comment, so I'm not sure what prompted the downvote, but I suspect that it may be related to the absence of any explanation of how the suggestions you offer would apply to the case of a newly created job. Please consider adding a discussion of how "[title]-elect" or "[title]-in-waiting" would work in that context.

Comment: Hi Sven. I thought I provided enough context, but it is difficult without understanding the precise use-case the asker is aiming for i.e. is it a department memo, a newspaper announcement, a letter of offer, or something else. Downvotes on the Internet are par for the course. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia use the term *”Preceded by: Office established”* where there is no predecessor, and I think you will be hard push to get better than that.

See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Livingstone

Comment: But the question asked for a word that can be applied to the person taking the new role.

Answer (score 0):

[Selectee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selectee) is a single word.

In years past the term was associated with military conscription in the US (Selective Service). However, that is an almost forgotten usage these days.
It now generally is used to identify one who is selected from a group of candidates.